# Paypal api payment in my site

Tags: paypal, payment

it could make payments on paypal without user passes through paypal page??

I do not want my users are directed to paypal page, I want to be the one to send all information to paypal, it is processed and give me an answer, but the user never leaves my website?

this is possible ??

Comment: Look into the [Seamless checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/seamless-checkout/) flow. Hth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For safety reasons an user can only complete a transaction directly trough PayPal site, maybe you can use frames to show the PayPal certified page in your site.

**EDIT:** From PayPal REST API: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

```
If the call is successful, PayPal returns a confirmation of the transaction with the state set to created.
[...]
Get payment approval
Please note the HATEOAS links in the example above. Direct the user to the approval_url on the PayPal site, so that the user can approve the payment. The user must approve the payment before you can execute and complete the sale.
```

**So you have to direct the user to the approval_url in order to make him/her approve the payment or you cannot execute and complete the sale.**

Comment: paypal api rest not allow me to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control your user experience (with no redirects), there are white label alternatives to Paypal.

Two options: Stripe offers a white label API for credit/debit transactions (2.9% + 30c transaction fee). SynapsePay offers a white label API for ACH payments (25c per transaction).